# rdbwselect in R not showing output

Tags: regression

I'm using the package [rdrobust](https://rdpackages.github.io/rdrobust/) in R and Stata. I planned to fully implement the analysis in R, but encountered a problem with the function `rdbwselect`. This function computes different bandwidths depending on the selection procedure. By default, the procedure is Mean Square Error `bwselect=mserd`. However, I'm interested in exploring other procedures and comparing them. I then tried `ALL=true`; which is the option that according to the package  "if specified, rdbwselect reports all available bandwidth selection procedures"

My issue is that, in R, `rdbwselect` is not showing me the bandwidths, not with the default not with the 'all' option or any other specification

```
x<-runif(1000,-1,1)
y<-5+3*x+2*(x>=0)+rnorm(1000)
## With default mserd
rdbwselect(y,x,)
## All selection procedures
rdbwselect(y,x,all= TRUE)
```

[Output rdwselect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsebR.png)

The output of both lines of rdbwselect code is exactly the same (see image), and it should not. I also try replicating the script from the [rdrobust article in The R Journal](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2015/RJ-2015-004/RJ-2015-004.pdf) (Page 49) and I don't get the same output as in the paper.

Nevertheless, the function is working in Stata 16

```
clear all
set obs 1000
set seed 1234
gen x = runiform(-1,1)
gen y = 5+3*x+2*(x>=0)+rnormal()
rdbwselect y x
rdbwselect y x, all
```

Could someone provide me with some guidance on why R is not showing me the complete expected output of the function `rdbwselect`?  I'm wondering if this is an issue related to my version of R? Could this be a bug with the R package or the specific function rdbwselect? How can I verify the computation behind rdbwselect?

I appreciate any advice or follow-up questions.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. All I needed to do was to embed the function within the `summary()` function

```
summary(rdbwselect(y,x,))
```

or add a pipe and the summary function

```
rdbwselect(y,x,all= TRUE) %>%
  summary()
```

I want to post it as this is nowhere mentioned in the package documentation nor the article in The R Journal.